# do.call() doesn't like base function "c" with a list

Tags: r, do.call

I have a larger section of code but I've narrowed down the problem to this -
So I want to return a concatenated list.

```
do.call(c,"X")
Error in do.call(c, "X") : second argument must be a list
```

So above it complains about the SECOND argument not being a list.

```
asimplelist=list(2,3,4)
class(asimplelist)
[1] "list"
do.call(c,asimplelist)
Error in do.call(c, asimplelist) : 
'what' must be a function or character string
```

Why will this not return a concatenated list ? C is a legit function, and it's being passed a list?

```
args(do.call)
function (what, args, quote = FALSE, envir = parent.frame()) 
NULL
```

So "what" is the function argument it is complaining about.

Comment: If you are still able to reproduce your problem, can you try `do.call("c",...` instead of `do.call(c,...`?

Answer (score 4):

I will answer "stealing" my answer from [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31471808/unlist-removes-class-in-list-elements-posixlt#comment50910310_31472036) by [Nick Kennedy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4998761/nick-kennedy):

It might be better to put the `c` in double quotes.

If the user has a non-function named `c` in the global environment, `do.call(c, dates)` will fail with the error `"Error in do.call(c, list(1:3)) : 'what' must be a character string or a function"`.

Clearly it may not be best practice to define `c`, but it's quite common for people to do `a <- 1; b <- 2; c <- 3`.

For most purposes, R still works fine in this scenario; `c(1, 2)` will still work, but `do.call(c, x)` won't.

Of course if the user has redefined `c` to be a function (e.g. `c <- sum`), then `do.call` will use the redefined function.